# Appfolders Management on Homepage

Tags: gnome, 18.04, directory

How can I add "appfolders" (folders in the view) on Ubuntu Homepage.

[image]
[image]
The GNOME shell extension named "[Appfolders Management extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/)" able to create custom folder view but can't do it on the desktop homepage.

Comment: to clarify, you want to add the "utilities" folder to the desktop? not the apps

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04Lts GNOME version 3.28.2, my desktop is different because I'm using custom gnome-shell theme.

Comment: yes I'm trying to add custom "utilities" folder to the desktop, how can I get it? which is the right command to get it?

Comment: found the folder... figuring out how to get it on the desktop.

Comment: looking around I so far can't find anyting... it seems to be strictly an extension of the activities view... so far google hasn't turned up anything... this would definitely be a cool feature if you can get it to work